# gganimate::transition_reveal() with jumpy behaviour if multiple steps are revealed

Tags: r, gganimate

I am trying to use `transition_reveal()` of the `gganimate` package, to show multiple steps at once, i.e., reveal not one but two days for each reveal.

The code is straight-forward as:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

# Base version, reveals one day at once
ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp, group = Month, color = factor(Month))) +
  geom_line() + 
  transition_reveal(Day)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Creating a second `Day2` variable, which holds the id for the reveals, is also straight-forward, but the output graph is quite buggy as it seems to accelerate (note the default of `ease_aes(default="linear")` is used).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

## Reveal two days at once, with jumpy behaviour
airquality %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate(Day2 = cumsum(Day %% 2 == 0)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Day, Temp, color = factor(Month))) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(Day2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any idea what the reason for this might be and how to fix it?